# Cannot Get GPIO0 High after programming RF settings ESP-12-Q

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to flash AI-Thinker ESP-12-Q module with custom compiled nodemcu image. When very first time the chip boots up it shows a message saying it has 8mbit (1MB) flash. On every document also images it is shown that this module has 32mbit (4MB) flash. Here is what i did and the result:

- To eliminate power problems, I power the module with 10 Amps lab supply (3.3 volts of course).
- There is a 3.3v ftdi module sitting between esp and computer.
- I'm using official flash download tool v2.4 from Espressif.
- As it is stated everywhere nodemcu image goes to 0x00000

After programming the nodemcu image esp module runs the nodemcu. I need to use ADC channel. When i say `adc.read(0)` it gives me `65535`. Then as is says everywhere i need to change 107th byte of config. To do that:

- Open esp flash download tool 2.4
- Goto RF InitConfig Page
- Press Defaults button
- Change CrystalFreq to 26MHz (because chip boots with 74880 baud)
- Change TOUT Pin Conf to TOUT_ADC_EN and voltage to 3.3v
- Change nothing else
- Press GenInitBin
- Goto FlashDownload page
- Select esp_init_data_setting.bin file to flash at address: 0x3FC00
- Press start. And everything seems ok.

Then the horror begins: When chip boots i can manage to catch a message like `system parameter error` then chip is not booting into nodemcu image. When i checked the pin GPIO0 the voltage reads around 1.9v. There is a 10K external pullup resistor on this pin. As the voltage reads like that, esp cannot boot into nodemcu image. When i force this pin to 3.3v by shorting the pullup resistor, it boots into nodemcu but with some errors (i'll try to catch them).

So the question is, what am i doing wrong?

EDIT #1:

This is the output of the chip:

```
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,0)

load 0x40100000, len 30288, room 16
tail 0
chksum 0xa5
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2268, room 8
tail 4
chksum 0x3f
load 0x3ffe88dc, len 8, room 4
tail 4
chksum 0xca
csum 0xca
system param error
ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff .... goes on for 100 meters.
```

EDIT #2:

I tried to load "factory defaults" to the chip as it is defined in the SDK v1.5

```
Flash size 32Mbit-C1:       1024KB+1024KB
boot_v1.2+.bin              0x00000
user1.2048.new.5.bin        0x01000
esp_init_data_default.bin   0x3fc000 (optional)
blank.bin                   0xfe000 & 0x3fe000
```

Then the chip starts to function normal. I tried with some AT commands, got answer as expected etc... Then I loaded the nodemcu image. It also functioned well as expected. Then the tricky part: This time I took the `esp_init_data_default.bin` from SDK1.5 and changed the *107th* byte to *0x21 (33 DEC)* by a hex editor. Then flashed the `esp_init_data_default.bin` and `blank.bin` files to the chip. Rebooted and checked what adc reads. I got some plausible results though. Seems like the chip goes normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be a definite answer because there's hardware involved but it may still be helpful (it's too long for a comment).

So, first things first try with a flasher that allows to set the flash size explicitly. I don't know the Espressif tool but many in the NodeMCU community are pretty [happy with esptool.py](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/flash/#esptool).

```
esptool.py --port <USB-port-with-ESP8266> write_flash -fm dio -fs 32m 0x00000 <nodemcu-firmware>.bin
```

Don't try to tinker with the firmware until you confirmed that this works (i.e. boot up w/o errors) and flash size and heap size look ok.

Next, if you use a recent NodeMCU firmware from the `dev` branch you can skip the byte-107-dance because [you can set it in Lua](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/adc/#adcforce_init_mode).

```
adc.force_init_mode(adc.INIT_ADC)
-- now reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm now deeply inspecting the issue. I'll add my findings as edit.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since there is not an eligible answer to this question. Because further tests with different h/w (esp12E) shows different characteristics. Your answer shows proven way to flash the chip.