# Errors flashing NodeMCU to ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I've been having a bit of a rough time trying to flash the latest dev firmware.  I've edited the question with a bunch of copy/paste examples from my cli and to clarify the steps I've taken so far.  Here's what I've tried doing:

- I downloaded the 1.4.0 master and dev versions of firmware from the custom build service.
- I tried to flash the 1.4.0 master version with this command:

  ```
  python esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash -fm=dio -fs=32m 0x00000 ~/git/nodemcu-
  firmware/bin/nodemcu_integer_1.4.0_master_20160531.bin 
  esptool.py v1.0.2-dev
  Connecting...
  Running Cesanta flasher stub...
  Flash params set to 0x0240
  Writing 405504 @ 0x0... 405504 (100 %)
  Wrote 405504 bytes at 0x0 in 35.2 seconds (92.2 kbit/s)...
  Leaving...
  ```
- This appears to succeed because I can connect to the devkit

  ```
  n?$B�
        ��4"*���4"*��B%,��� C�
  NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
          branch: master
          commit: c8037568571edb5c568c2f8231e4f8ce0683b883
          SSL: false
          modules: file,gpio,i2c,net,node,rtcfifo,rtcmem,rtctime,tmr,uart,wifi,ws2812
   build  built on: 2016-06-01 02:58
   powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.4.0
  lua: cannot open init.lua
  >
  ```
- I downloaded v1.5.1 nonos of the espressif sdk to get the esp_init_data_default.bin I had to do this because the devkit was running 0.9.6
- I tried to flash the 1.4.0 dev version of the firmware with this command:

  ```
  python esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash -fm=dio -fs=32m 0x00000 ~/git/nodemcu-firmware/bin/nodemcu_integer_1.4.0_dev_20160531.bin 0x3fc000 ~/git/nodemcu-firmware/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin 
  esptool.py v1.0.2-dev
  Connecting...
  Running Cesanta flasher stub...
  Flash params set to 0x0240
  Writing 401408 @ 0x0... 401408 (100 %)
  Wrote 401408 bytes at 0x0 in 34.8 seconds (92.3 kbit/s)...
  Writing 4096 @ 0x3fc000... 4096 (100 %)
  Wrote 4096 bytes at 0x3fc000 in 0.4 seconds (90.0 kbit/s)...
  Leaving...
  ```
- This appears to fail because when I try to connect to the devkit I get nothing but gibberish.  I have tried to connect with EVERY baud setting and it doesn't appear to improve the gibberish at all.

  ```
  rll|l�|l�b|�rbb�nnlnn��bplrlrlp�n�lbn�|l�b�nn�ll`nn
                                               lnr�n

                                                     b��`p�n�

                                                                r���bn�|llb�nn�l`nnl�l`nr�n

                                                                                               ��l``�n


                                                                                                       ��b�nl�
                                                                                                              ��nn�
                                                                                                                   lp�n�

    r���lbn�|b�nn�ll`
  ```

The master version of the firmware works very well, but as I said its missing a couple things from wifi and ws2812 modules that I want to use.  The dev version of the firmware does flash, but when I try to use screen to connect to the devkit all I get is gibberish and a Lua prompt never shows up.  I'm giving up now I don't know what to try next so can somebody please guide me?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a bug with `screen` that keeps it from communicating to the devkit on firmware versions 1.5 and above.  To work around this issue you can either use putty for linux (available from apt-get if you're on ubuntu) or downgrade your firmware to 1.4

See this answer on SuperUser for some detailed info:
https://superuser.com/questions/810937/how-can-i-set-the-parity-bits-when-using-screen-to-access-a-serial-port

P.s. I have only confirmed this bug on armhf compiled binaries.  It is possible that the x86 binaries work just fine as I have not tested it, though the Q&A on SuperUser that I linked seems to imply that screen on x86 will have problems too.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording regarding branches and versions is a bit confusing (to me at least). `dev` is based on SDK v1.5.1 while for `master` it's 1.4.0.

You don't need to flash the firmware *plus* the SDK. The firmware itself is enough. Since you reference our flashing docs I assume you got the `esptool.py` command right.

Two things worth noting:

- I reckon you mention `esp_init_data_default.bin` because of the byte-107-dance? No longer necessary if you're on the `dev` branch because of [`adc.force_init_mode()`](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/modules/adc/#adcforce_init_mode), we just [had this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37553861/131929). Or is this because you previously had old 0.9.x firmware on the device? If so, did you get the address for `esp_init_data_default.bin` right i.e. aligned to your device's flash size?
- We've got auto-baud detection in `dev`. I'm not sure how nice this plays with `screen`. Try setting 115'200 explicitly or [try ESPlorer](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/upload/).

**Update**

Allow me to say that I believe you created a total mess. Also, I have reason to believe the reports and the output in your Q ain't the whole truth.

- Again, there's no such thing as v1.4 `dev`. `dev` is based on SDK 1.5.1,  `master` uses 1.4.
- You claim to use my [custom build service](http://nodemcu-build.com/index.php). Yet, in your first cmd line excerpt the filename and path is `~/git/nodemcu-firmware/bin/nodemcu_integer_1.4.0_master_20160531.bin`. This hints that you're building the firmware yourself (using my [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelstoer/nodemcu-build/)?). The file names generated by the build service use the pattern `nodemcu-<branch>-<number>-modules-<timestamp>-integer|float` while my Docker image by default generates something like `nodemcu_integer|float_<branch>_<timestamp>`.
- But then again your second snippet undoubtedly shows that you successfully load a firmware from the NodeMCU `master` branch built by my custom build service.
- And then you flash something like "1.4.0 dev" (doesn't exist) built locally PLUS `esp_init_data_default.bin`? I don't get it. The [NodeMCU flashing docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/flash/#upgrading-from-sdk-09x-firmware) say that you only need `esp_init_data_default.bin` when directly upgrading from 0.9.x - if at all. So, if you already have `master` (1.4) there's absolutely no need for that.

Sorry, really can't help any further. I believe the road to success for you is really simple:

- got to http://nodemcu-build.com/
- select the `dev` branch plus all desired modules
- download the binary
- `esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash -fm=dio -fs=32m 0x00000 nodemcu-dev-N-modules-2016-06-03-<time>-integer.bin`

Comment: Hello Marcel,  I modified my question based on some of the things you sid here.  I did previously have an older 0.9.6 firmware on the device. The flashsize of the device is 4194304 so I think that means the 0x3fc000 address for the sdk is correct.

Comment: Since you re-wrote the question I had to follow suit with an update myself.

Comment: It turns out that the problem was with screen though explicitly setting the baud didn't solve it.  Eventually I tried running putty for linux to connect to the devkit and that worked perfectly.  I understand your confusion about the file names because I renamed the files to follow the naming convention of previous versions of the firmware that I all ready had on my computer and it turns out that when I renamed the dev file I accidentally hit 1.4 instead of 1.5... so that explains that.