# HTTP GET in LUA/NodeMCU

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I'm trying to send a HTTP GET each time I press a button :

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","PWD")
function loop() 
    if wifi.sta.status() == 5 then
        -- Stop the loop
        tmr.stop(0)
    else
        print("Connecting...")
    end
end
tmr.alarm(0, 100, 1, function() loop() end)
print(wifi.sta.getip())

outpin_led = 1
inpin_button = 3

gpio.mode(outpin_led,gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(inpin_button,gpio.INPUT)
light_on = false

function light()
    if not light_on then
        -- turn the light on
        gpio.write(outpin_led,gpio.HIGH)
        light_on = true
        http.get("https://google.com", function(clt, data)
            print(data)
        end)
    else
        -- turn the light off
        gpio.write(outpin_led,gpio.LOW)
        light_on = false
    end
end

gpio.trig(inpin_button,"down",light)
```

The line containing `http.get` is throwing this error message :

`> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (stdin:6: attempt to index global 'http' (a nil value))`

I made sure my NodeMCU build contained the `http` module by compiling it through `http://nodemcu-build.com/`

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: The only sensible explanation is indeed that your firmware is missing the HTTP module. However, I can confirm that all three builds you triggered today should include it (according to my records). Are you sure that you actually flashed one of them? When the device boots it should print "NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com" and a number of config parameters to UART, an example can be seen at http://stackoverflow.com/q/37559525/131929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marcel Stör pointed out, it was indeed an issue during the flashing of the firmware.

Thanks a lot for your reply and for your work on http://nodemcu-build.com/.